# Can a non-electrolytic capacitor be made from activated carbon?

Tags: capacitor

I’ve been seeing a lot of super capacitors made from activated carbon powder particles bonded together with a resin to form a solid plate. Activated carbon has a very high surface area that’s why it commonly used in super capacitors, but super capacitors are electrolytic. Can I still use activated carbon in a regular non-electrolytic unpolarized capacitor? I want to make an unpolarized capacitor with activated carbon. Activated carbon plate should be better than a metal plate right because of the higher surface area.

Comment: How do you propose to form the second plate?

Comment: Unclear. Do you want non-electrolytic or non-polarized?

Comment: Non-electrolytic and non-polarized means the same exact thing. Both mean a capacitor without an electrolyte. Only with a dielectric In between. Also, I’m wanting both plates to be made out of activated carbon. I’m asking if it’s possible because I’ve only seen electrolytic capacitors use carbon so far. I wonder why the companies that make these things don’t use activated carbon yet.

Comment: No, it doesn't. There are non-polarized electrolytic capacitors.

Answer (score 4):

It seems somewhat pointless, to be honest.  The whole deal making a large surface area advantageous as a capacitor electrode is that you get a large area close to the other electrode.  But for that to work, the other electrode needs to actually get into most of the pores and other surface-enlarging features.  Two *independent* large-surface solid electrodes don't really buy you anything.

Now one could imagine liquifying the other electrode only during manufacturing of the capacitor so that it follows the large-surface features of the other electrode.  But it's hard to imagine a process of solidification that would not cause serious damage to the other electrode right away, let alone by differences in expansion during temperature changes in operation.

And if solidification depends on combining chemicals, then a process mixing them up well enough to have the solidification reach every pore of the electrode reliably seems ambitious.

Comment: Tantalum capacitors are made this way (second paragraph)

Comment: @user253751 For a while :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maxwell supercaps that have the same carbon electrode material, they say are "non-polarized in theory". But in practice, it makes a difference in the long term even though in the short term the breakdown voltage is non-polarized. The carbon gives a very low ESR for large caps and may also have some effect on the short-term memory caused by the double layer effect. This is observed by the rapid pulse of high current causing a large voltage change to drift back to near the previous voltage.

This is not the long-term memory effect that NiCd batteries had.

Comment: Yeah I’m just looking to see if a capacitor with no electrolyte with activated carbon as the plate material is possible. I’m looking to make my own high surface area high voltage capacitor

Comment: I was saying both non electrolytic and non polarized.

Comment: Are you planning anything different than this ? http://pdf.xuebalib.com:1262/xuebalib.com.2022.pdf